# pc shutdown when plugging in headphones

Tags: power-management, shutdown, headphones, jack

My laptop goes off when plugging in headphones. This only happens running on batteries. Windows 10 works ok so it's a linux related problem. Tested on Ubuntu, Elementary and now Apricity.

I saw another thread advising to disable power saving mode on Intel HD Audio, but I didn't find the file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave` on my distro

My laptop is Acer Aspire R5-571T-57Z0

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem but fixed it by removing laptop-mode-tools package by running:

```
sudo apt remove --purge laptop-mode-tools
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but laptop-mode-tools is not installed :(

Comment: Correction: It works for Ubuntu!! now I'm looking for a solution for Apricity Os. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a power management related problem and the solution for me was to disable power management for audio when running on bateries.
In my actual distro the power management configuration is done by TLP.
All TLP settings are stored in the config file /etc/default/tlp
I edited this file with root permissions and changed the line

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
```

for

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0
```

I saved the file and rebooted.